# esxi cannot create vSwitch out of memory

Tags: esxi

When I try to create a new vswitch on esxi host gives this error on vmkernel

```
WARNING: Net: 1625: vSwitch2: can't create device: Out of memory
```

Checked the resorces it is far from being used.
 
Had anyone have similar issue and if yes some tips how to troubleshoot it?

Comment: This is the log from vmkernel.log:
2019-03-18T14:01:09.864Z cpu8:32750733)NetPortset: 854: activating portset #4 as vSwitch2 (etherswitch) with 4096 ports, index mask is 0xfff
2019-03-18T14:01:09.865Z cpu8:32750733)NetPort: 1392: enabled port 0x4000006 with mac 00:00:00:00:00:00
2019-03-18T14:01:09.865Z cpu8:32750733)WARNING: Net: 1625: vSwitch2: can't create device: Out of memory
2019-03-18T14:01:09.865Z cpu8:32750733)NetPort: 1586: disabled port 0x4000006

Comment: Issue solved with a clean reboot of the esxi server I could not reproduce the problem. The cause could be related to the vsphere client that removing the vmnic from the vswitch in realaty it did not even if graficaly was showing that it is. In this case when Itrying to create a new vswitch was giving the error of "can't create device: out of memory"